# How to divide digits and compare them, in C

Tags: c

Write a program that will find the largest number smaller than N that is totally different from a given number X. One number is totally different from other only if it doesn't contain any of the digits from the other number. N and X are read from standard input. The problem should be solved without the use of arrays.

Example Input 1:  400 897

Example Output 1: 366

Example Input 2: 1000 1236498

Example Output 2:777

No it's not homework, it was on one of the midterms and it's been killing me. I though about taking the first numbers last digit with %10 then taking the second numbers digit with %10 comparing them but...I just can't get it to work...I ended up with an endless loop...I just don't understand how to get every digit of the numbers and compare them to the other number.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main () {
int N, X, num_N, num_X, i, lastDigit_N, lastDigit_X, flag, smaller_than_N;

scanf("%d%d", &N, &X);
smaller_than_N = N - 1;

for (i = smaller_than_N; i > 0; i--) {
num_N = i;
num_X = X;
flag = 0;

while (num_N > 0) {
lastDigit_N = num_N % 10;

while (num_X > 0) {
lastDigit_X = num_X % 10;

if (lastDigit_N == lastDigit_X) {
break;
}

else {
flag = 1;
}

num_X /= 10;
}
num_N /= 10;
}

if(flag) {
printf("%d", i);    
break;
}
}

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You could iterate from 0 to N using a `for` loop.

Comment: Step through the code in a debugger, line by line, while checking all variable values.

Comment: It is probably easier to do this with [itoa](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/itoa/).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch you know I totally forgot about that little word of awesome :D thanks man. :D

Comment: Why wouldn't 'Example Output 1' be 366?

Answer (score 2):

You could build a bitmask for your numbers showing the digits which are contained.

```
uint16_t num2bitmask(int number)
{
    uint16_t result = 0;
    while (number) {
        int digit = number % 10;
        number /= 10;
        result |= (1 << digit);
    }
    return result;
}
```

With this function, you can create your bitmask for `X` and then iterate from `N-1` down to 1 until you find a value which doesn't have any bits in common with the other value.

Comment: Nice idea! @College19: Once you have built the bismask for the other number while iterating you can `&` them and check if the result is `0`, if it is you have found a number that is 'totally different' from the other number.

Comment: @glglgl I would if I knew how, they don't teach sht at my college. Just oh hey these are variables these are arrays which can be also matrices and go figure out the whole language and it's functionality on your own. Thanks though I'm going to check out what a bitmask is and how to use it :D

Answer (score 0):

If you have a number with digits d_1, d_2, ..., d_n, and you're allowed to use digits in the set D, then possible solutions look like:

```
d_1, ..., d_{i-1}, max(d in D | d < d_i), max(d in D), ..., max(d in D).
```

That is, the digits are the same up to some point, then the next digit is as large as possible while being below the input digit, then the rest are just as large as possible.

Not all these "solutions" will be valid, but if you iterate through them in reverse order (there's exactly n for an input number of size n), the first valid one you find is the answer.

Some code, including tests:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int digit_length(int a) {
    int r = 0;
    while (a) {
        a /= 10;
        r += 1;
    }
    return r;
}

int get_digit(int a, int k) {
    while (k--) a /= 10;
    return a % 10;
}

int largest_different(int a, int b) {
    int lena = digit_length(a);
    int invalid = b ? 0 : 1;
    for (; b; b /= 10) invalid |= 1 << (b % 10);
    int max_valid = 9;
    while (max_valid >= 0 && (invalid & (1 << max_valid)))
        max_valid--;
    if (max_valid == -1) return -1;
    for (int i = 0; i < lena; i++) {
        int d = get_digit(a, i) - 1;
        while (d >= 0 && (invalid & (1 << d)))d--;
        if (d < 0) continue;
        int solution = 0;
        for (int k = lena - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
            solution *= 10;
            solution += (k < i ? max_valid : k > i ? get_digit(a, k) : d);
        }
        return solution;
    }
    return -1;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    struct {int n; int x; int want;} examples[] = {
        {400, 897, 366},
        {1000, 1236498, 777},
        {998, 123, 997},
    };
    int error = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(examples) / sizeof(*examples); i++) {
        int got = largest_different(examples[i].n, examples[i].x);
        if (got != examples[i].want) {
            error = 1;
            printf("largest_different(%d, %d) = %d, want %d\n",
                examples[i].n, examples[i].x, got, examples[i].want);
        }
    }
    return error;
}
```

There's not always a solution. In that case, the function returns -1.